# Targeting a specific div with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I'm using Hertzen's html2canvas.js, and tried to adjust the example code so that it targets a specific div instead of the entire body of a document:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

A sample of what I'm trying to accomplish is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ununkg3a/

On clicking the "Save PNG" button, I want to append an image of the jQuery generated squares that I'm targeting in a specific div. In the code, it appears that it's appending something, but it doesn't have a height. When I try to set a height with the output, it still doesn't work as expected.

Is it not possible to accomplish something like this? Whenever I change document.body to another element, the screenshot doesn't render anymore, although it does render when I change it back to document.body. Someone told me that I'd have to crop the image with js, but that seems a little hacky.

Comment: Which document.body did you change?

Comment: did you try `document.getElementById('div-id').appendChild(canvas);`?

Comment: Hmm... I tried to add that code on a fiddle : works with @Pete idea. https://jsfiddle.net/9nhx4Ljb/1/  but interesting results.

Comment: @HalasiTomi and @Pete - I tried to set up a variable, `var selectDiv = document.getElementById("tag");` and replaced "document.body" with it, but just couldn't get it to target the entire div as expected. I'm wondering if another script could possibly get this to work?

Comment: It's working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/60wmsa6p/1/

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version

Comment: Thanks @Tomato, you've made me realize that there's some other issue going on with what I'm trying to do. I've revised my question with additional info to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It can: it's the first attribute.**
[(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/60wmsa6p/1/)

*Example:*

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('test')).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

---

In your example, canvas2html can't find out the height of your div. Because of that it falls back to 0px height, so you won't see anything.

Give width to the #art then you can count the height manually and use that.

*Mathematic example:*
art_square_width = 10px
art_square_height = 10px
art_square_amount = 500
art_width = 250px
art_height = art_width / (art_width /  art_square_width) * art_square_height = 200px

[(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ununkg3a/1/)